# What to do with USB Webcam "Not enough bandwidth for new device state" Issue?

Tags: usb, kernel, webcam, logitech, xhci-hcd

There is apparently a bug in the xhci_hcd driver since more than 5 years that keeps my Logitech C922 Webcam from working on my fully updated Ubuntu 18.04.

The issue is apparently easily reproducible and has been reference many times, for example here:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1411604, https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/3/1/59, https://community.logitech.com/s/question/0D55A000073Xw85SAC/brio-in-linux, https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=278895. Just keep looking in Google for "Not enough bandwidth for new device state -28".

What can I do?

Comment: In most cases, all of your USB devices share the same bandwidth.  This error suggests that you don't have enough. While you may have X number of ports, you may not be able to use all at the same time.  I'd disconnect all other devices and see if that makes a change.

Comment: @Nmath, didn't you see that this is a well documented bug in the USB driver of the Linux kernel??? My question is about how really to proceed.

Comment: I've tried to contact the maintainer of the xhci_hcd USB kernel module (no success so far...), and I'm now trying to become a member of the USB kernel mailing list in order to post this bug. These was the type of advice I was looking for. Any additional ideas?

Comment: Thanks Nmath! You are right about the different causes. However, they look very similar... Concerning the Webcam: It is working with cheese and Skype when there is no VM audio going through USB. This condition is exactly as described in the other bug descriptions.

Comment: It worked in Windows without problems... I'm an open-source developer since >15 years, but this is a case where this development model fails so badly. I can't believe it. There are literally 10.000s of users affected who would like to change from Windows 7 to Linux...

Comment: @fabrer I share and understand your frustration about this issue, but I don't think there's anything fundamentally wrong with this "development model". My own webcam stopped being compatible with my desktop Mac computer after one OSX update, and neither the manufacturer for being an "old" model (<2 of years old!) nor Apple did anything at all, and if they don't do it, nobody can. My only solution was to buy a new camera and pray it continues working after each OSX update. To point: it seems that there's a workaround for this disabling something in the Bios, tho I haven't tried. Sorry.

Comment: @Nmath I may agree with you fundamentally and in a general case, but just to clearify: this is something related to the USB controller, nor the webcam driver. I'm experiencing the same issue intermitently with several different devices (mostly an android phone and a USB headphone set). Sometimes I just reboot the laptop leaving them plugged and they all work fine after booting (USB bandwidth stretched?), but sometimes they wont. I've been using Linux from the very first two 3.5 floppies and I do plan to continue doing so, but this is one of the most frustrating bugs I have found

Answer (score 0):

After a long time I finally got it working. I have to plug the cam directly into a laptop USB port. It fails completely when plugging it into my TB16 docking station. Also, I had to eliminate my previous Dell D3100 docking station.

Comment: so i just read this, FYI that while a 'docking station' provides extra USB ports, there's a max amount of bandwidth that the docking station's connector to the system can provide, and it sounds like you're simply exhausting the bandwidth available on that hardware connection between the computer and the docking port.  Docking stations don't increase your available USB bandwidth, just the number of available ports.  ;)

Comment: Nope. D3100 is "USB 3" while the C922 cam is "USB 2". Checkout https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-usb@vger.kernel.org/msg113817.html 
I believe at the end it's a hardware quirk in the D3100, but the Windows guys somehow got it working, while the Linux guys insist that the specs are wrong. Greg Kroah-Hartman wrote: "You're probably not aware of this, but with xHCI USB-3 controllers, bandwidth decisions are made by the hardware/firmware, not by the software.  In particular, these decisions are not made by the kernel driver; they are made by the xHCI controller itself."